# What does ">>" in the get_block_reward do?

Tags: monero-forks, source

I'm creating my own fork of Monero and I was looking at the block reward function and I found this line in the file "src/cryptonote_basic/cryptonote_basic_impl.cpp"

```
uint64_t base_reward = (MONEY_SUPPLY - already_generated_coins) >> emission_speed_factor;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right shift.

>> N means shifting right by N bits, which is, for unsigned quantities, dividing by 2 to the Nth power. Rounded down obviously.